# Is there a way to filter or sort data in a RESTful API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

From my understanding (although I am just learning this so I am likely wrong), we use URIs in RESTful APIs to identify resources.

In particular, I've read this comment many times across the web:

> @RequestParam is more useful on a traditional web application where data is mostly passed in the query parameters while @PathVariable is more suitable for RESTful web services where URL contains values.

When reading this, it seems like we need to use @PathVariable to properly build a RESTful API instead of using @RequestParam (which is not RESTFUL given the way it identifies resources through query parameters instead of URIs). Is this correct? If so, how can I build a RESTful API that is also capable of sorting or filtering like you would be able to do with @RequestParam?

An example is here:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
Resource<Car> get(@PathVariable Long id) {
   Car car = carService.findById(id);
   return assembler.toResource(car);
}
```

vs

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
Resource<Car> get(@RequestParam(required = true) Long id) {
    Car car = carService.findById(id);
    return assembler.toResource(car);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should examine the `Pageable` type in Spring. Generally, what you've shown here is called something like an *item resource*: It's one specific Car, specified by ID at `/cars/{id}`. There's nothing to sort or filter. Those are applied to the *collection resource* `/cars`, perhaps something like `/cars?sort=year&page=0&size=10`. Spring has [integrated support](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-web-support) for automatically extracting query parameters indicating sorting and paging and passing those instructions to Spring Data repositories.

Answer (score 2):

For filtering, one option is to use Spring Data JPA [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications), which allows you to return entities that match your specification, which you define as predicates using the Spring criteria API.

Spring Data JPA also includes [sorting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting) capability, utilized by either providing a PageRequest or using Sort directly. Spring defines [special parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) such as *Pageable* and *Sort*, which can be used to apply paging and sorting to your queries dynamically.

Or you can sort [via URL parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html) indicating the name of the property on which you wish to sort the results.